How to add a Physical Material to a Box Brush in UE5
I am creating a world in UE5 and I set 2 surface types: Tiles and Grass. And I made 2 Box Brushes one with some dimensions and the other with 200 more in scale and made the brush type subtractive. And I added a material to my "floor" and I want to assign also a Physical Material to it so it knows, there are tiles, but I cannot find anywhere the Phys. Material Override so I can add that.
I was browsing through Google and Youtube for the past hour, couldn't find anything that helped me.
I made my world using box brushes because I found it easier than replicating Static Meshes.
My question is: should I not use box brushes if I want to set that physical material, or is there any chance I can do that with box brushes?
Thank you in advance.
